# Concatenating variable and regexp expression in Puppet

Tags: regex, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

Is it possible at all? My use case is setting wildcard domain's docroot. I have a variable

```
$docroot = "/var/www"
```

and, inside `apache::vhost {}` I'm trying to set

```
virtual_docroot' => "{$docroot}/%-2+",
```

That however throws an error saying:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at ' => "$docroot/%-2+",
    docroot          => $docroot,
    serveraliases    => ['; expected '}' at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests/init.pp:22 on node localhost
```

My guess is that the whole expression is treated as a regexp, and `$` treated as a part of the whole expression. Hence my doubts whether that's possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be an orphaned apostrophe, misplaced after `virtual_docroot`, and copied from [puppetlabs-apache documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache), where the faulty code is:

```
apache::vhost { 'subdomain.loc':
  vhost_name => '*',
  port       => '80',
  virtual_docroot' => '/var/www/%-2+',
  docroot          => '/var/www',
  serveraliases    => ['*.loc',],
}
```

Removing the apostrophe fixed the problem. Answer to my question is to set that particular configuration line as:

```
virtual_docroot => "$docroot/%-2+",
```

Notice the omitted `{}` characters.